# Dynamic Includes Set A Default Include PHP

Tags: php

I have the following script to dynamically include pages into the index.php:

```
<?php
   $_GET["page"] = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "home.php";

         $page = $_GET['page'];
     $pages = array('home', 'solutions', 'projects', 'about', 'contact');
if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        include($page);
    }
    else {
    echo 'Page not found. Return to
    <a href="index.php">index</a>';
    }
}
    else {
    include("home.php");
}
?>
```

When I type in "localhost/mysitename/index.php" in the adress bar of the browser I get the index.php loading up good but in the content area where the dynamic includes should happen it says: "Page not found. Return to index".So how can I set a default page to be included when the index.php is being loaded? I 'm pretty new to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `.php` here

```
$_GET["page"] = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "home.php";
```

Should be

```
$_GET["page"] = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "home”;
```

Comment: @mookar, if that solved it, please green checkmark as accepted answer. You can also up vote good answers, welcome to SO!